# How to add or remove function based on innerWidth JavaScript native

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm trying to add/remove function when screen width is bigger than or less than, but code below not working, any suggestions?

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if(window.innerHeight > 768){
       window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolling);
    }else{
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrolling);
       sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.remove('fixed-sidebar-home');
       sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.remove('fixed-bottom-sidebar')
    }
});
```

callback scrolling:

```
const scrolling = () => {
      sectionFixedNavLeftSide.getBoundingClientRect().top <= (screen.width / 
      50 * 2.7) ? 
      sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.add('fixed- 
      sidebar-home') : 
      sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.remove('fixed- 
      sidebar-home');
      
      sectionFixedNavRightSide.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - screen.width 
      / 2.85 <= 0 ? 
      sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.add('fixed-bottom- 
      sidebar') : 
      sectionFixedNavLeftSide.firstElementChild.classList.remove('fixed- 
      bottom-sidebar');
}
```

Comment: Provide more detail please. What are you trying to do also tell what is the ‘scrolling’ callback function doing?

Comment: @iftikharyk scrolling callback is adding or removing classes based on condition, code added to question, bcs here it is messed up

Comment: Looking at your code, are you aware of the CSS `position:sticky`, which allows you to achieve the effect you appear to be after, but without any JS at all?

Comment: I noticed that you wrote `innerWidth` but in the code you use `innerHeight`. Maybe you are just hunting a typo here? The code seems to work fine when I run it.

Comment: @JonasOsburg eh, no, result is still same, seems like eventListener isn't being removed when screen size is less than 768

Comment: Seems `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` by conditions working. That means `scrolling` function works too. Maybe issues on element `sectionFixedNavLeftSide`? Provide full codes.

Comment: Is `const scrolling` a local variable?  If so, that's why `removeEventListener` isn't working.  The function passed to `removeEventListener` must be the same as that passed to `addEventListener`.  So try moving the `scrolling` function to global scope.